# How to remove empty space in second alinea?

Tags: python, html

I'm tring to remove the extra space and "rebtel.bootstrappedData" in the second alinea but for some reason it won't work.

This is my output

```
"welcome_offer_cuba.block_1_title":"SaveonrechargetoCuba","welcome_offer_cuba.block_1_cta":"Sendrecharge!","welcome_offer_cuba.block_1_cta_prebook":"Pre-bookRecarga","welcome_offer_cuba.block_1_footprint":"Offervalidfornewusersonly.","welcome_offer_cuba.block_2_key":"","welcome_offer_cuba.block_2_title":"Howtosendarecharge?","welcome_offer_cuba.block_2_content":"<ol><li>Simplyenterthenumberyou’dliketosendrechargeinthefieldabove.</li><li>Clickthe“{{buttonText}}”button.</li><li>CreateaRebtelaccountifyouhaven’talready.</li><li>Done!Yourfriendshouldreceivetherechargeshortly.</li></ol>","welcome_offer_cuba.block_3_title":"DownloadtheRebtelapp!","welcome_offer_cuba.block_3_content":"Sendno-feerechargeandenjoythebestcallingratestoCubainoneplace."},"canonical":{"string":"<linkrel=\"canonical\"href=\"https://www.rebtel.com/en/rates/\"/>"}};
            rebtel.bootstrappedData={"links":{"summary":{"collection":"country_links","ids":[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],"params":{"locale":"en"},"meta":{}},"data":[{"title":"A","links":[{"iso2":"AF","route":"afghanistan","name":"Afghanistan","url":"/en/rates/afghanistan/","callingCardsUrl":"/en/calling-cards/afghanistan/","popular":false},{"iso2":"AL","route":"albania","name":"Albania","url":"/en/rates/albania/
```

And this is the code I used:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.rebtel.com/en/rates/"

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

x = range(132621, 132624)
script = soup.find_all("script")[4].text.strip()[38:]

print(script)
```

What should I add to "script" so it will remove the empty spaces?

Comment: You could use the [strip](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_strip.asp) method.

Comment: I tried that by adding strip() to the end but it doesn't change for me.

Comment: I've also tried: script = soup.find_all("script")[4].text.strip()[38:].lstrip() but that didn't work either

Comment: When I execute your code, I have a huge output. Did you change something on your code to obtain the output you gave?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. There are two alinea's and I'm trying to remove the spaces from both alinea's. I managed to strip the empty spaces in front of the first alinea but not from the second alinea. So I've only copied the second alinea part because it would otherwise be to big

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Original answer

You can change the definition of your `script` variable by :

```py
script = soup.find_all("script")[4].text.replace("\t", "")[38:]
```

It will remove all tabulations on your text and so the alineas.

## Edit after conversation in the comments

You can use the following code to extract the data in json :

```py
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.rebtel.com/en/rates/"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
script = list(filter(None, soup.find_all("script")[4].text.replace("\t", "").split("\r\n")))
app_data = json.loads(script[1].replace("rebtel.appData = ", "")[:-1])
bootstrapped_data = json.loads(script[2].replace("rebtel.bootstrappedData = ", ""))
```

I extracted the lines of the script with `split("\r\n")` and get the wanted data from there.

Comment: Thanks! If I want to remove "rebtel.bootstrappedData" and the space that occurs when removing this so the two alinea's are connected. What do I need to add to this new variable: script = soup.find_all("script")[4].text.replace("\t", "")[38:].replace("rebtel.bootstrappedData", "")

Comment: I think you should use `.replace("\nrebtel.bootstrappedData = ", "")` in order to remove the ` = ` at the end and the `\n` (the break line before). With that, the two lines are connected.

Comment: Your welcome ! If the solution solved your problem, think to mark it accepted in order to close your question.

Comment: One last question! I only wanted the information for "rebtel.appData" and "rebtel.bootstrappedData". When I filled in soup.find_all("script", "bootstrappedData") it didn't show me the information. Is there another way to retrieve that information?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I really appreciate it a lot. I'm currently busy with Webscraping and since I don't have a lot of experience I have been struggling a lot. I was wondering if you have any experience with it and so yes if I can ask you a question only when I get stuck?

Comment: Of course you can !

Comment: Okay thanks! I will leave this question open then.

Comment: You have my email on my profile to contact me. Please close this question since it is resolved

Comment: Great! I've added it to my contacts. Have a nice day :)